# Looking for a simple way to implement basic user roles

Tags: c#, authorization, asp.net-mvc-5, roles, identity

I'm building an intranet application using Windows authentication and I have pulled my users to my local DB, keeping only the information I need from Active Directory.

I would like to assign roles to my users (Admin or user) and restrict the admin views.

Is there a simple way to do this without going the Identity route? I've looked into it and it seems overkill and honestly rather confusing. Would there be a way to create a utility class which could be used as an annotation and simply restrict views depending on current user role property?

Comment: Try http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358525/simple-custom-roles-for-windows-authentication-in-asp-net?rq=1

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Giving it a try right away, thanks.

Comment: No worries. Hope it helps!

Comment: I've been trying to implement this but not fully successful yet. Do I have to call IsUserInRole manually? GetRolesForUser seems to be called automatically when I try to open a restricted view but I get a credential requests. I was hoping that the IsUserInRole would be called at that point to check if access to said view is allowed for logged in user. Any idea? Thank you!

Comment: As far as I am aware (not looked into it myself) it sounds like the GetRolesForUser is called automatically at some point. You can use IsUserInRole to work on certain logic, otherwise use the Authorize attribute to restrict access to controller actions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a simple solution for those interested. I decided to avoid using any Role Provider altogether because all you really need is a method that authenticate the request and another to check the user's role. In my Global.asax I added the following method, [taken from this blog post](http://brockallen.com/2012/05/23/think-twice-about-using-roleprovider/):

```
void Application_PostAuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var ctx = HttpContext.Current;
    if (ctx.Request.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        string[] roles = LookupRolesForUser(ctx.User.Identity.Name);
        var newUser = new GenericPrincipal(ctx.User.Identity, roles);
        ctx.User = Thread.CurrentPrincipal = newUser;
    }
}
```

The only method you have to implement yourself is LookupRolesForUser. Mine looks like this (the Linq will depend on your database structure, I have 3 tables for mine: User, Role and User_Role):

```
public string[] LookupRolesForUser(string username)
{
    using (MyContext db = new MyContext())
    {
        var user = db.Users.FirstOrDefault(u => u.Username.Equals(username, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) || u.Email.Equals(username, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));

        var roles = from ur in user.Roles
                    from r in db.Roles
                    where ur.RoleId == r.RoleId
                    select r.RoleName;
        if (roles != null)
            return roles.ToArray();
        else
            return new string[] { }; ;
    }
}
```

Then you can use the Authorize annotion in your controllers as such:

```
 [Authorize(Roles = "Administrator")]
 public class AdminController : BaseController
```