# Is it possible to switch Role Providers in code?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, windows-authentication, asp.net-authorization

I have an ASP.Net MVC 5 web app that needs to use AD groups to allow general access but I also need to have roles within the App that the application needs to maintain at a very granular level. Is it possible to use multiple Role Providers?  1 for AD groups and the other using a custom Role provider?   I would like to use the Attributes on the Controllers to restrict access but I can't seem to see how to make it use SQL Roles and Ad Groups, when they are maintained separately?

I guess I would like to know if through code if I can switch between the 2 different rolleManagers?  I'm not even sure if I can have more than one, but it it seems weird if I can't since I can specify the default one?

```
<roleManager enabled="true" defaultProvider="CustomRoleProvider">
  <providers>
    <clear />
    <add name="AspNetWindowsTokenRoleProvider" type="System.Web.Security.WindowsTokenRoleProvider"  applicationName="/"  />
    <add name="CustomRoleProvider" type="Reconciliation.CustomRoleProvider.CustomRoleProvider" applicationName="/" />
  </providers>
</roleManager>
```

In some cases I would like to use Use.IsInRole("RoleName") and in others I would like to query Active Directory instead of the SQL Roles table.

I'm going to leave this open, because i was not able to figure out how to switch role providers in code. To Solve my problem I ended up using Global Filter with the Authorize class to allow me to query AD and determine if the person was authorize to access the application.

Comment: *From Sukanya:* Trying to understand your question. Do you want to show the custom role names instead of the AD group names in the application (ex: dropdown)?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Simple custom roles for windows authentication in asp. net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10358525/simple-custom-roles-for-windows-authentication-in-asp-net)

Comment: It looks like you only need Windows *authentication*. A role provider handles authorization, not authentication. You can use Windows authentication and any other role provider you want for authorization. Have you tried using only your custom role provider?